# Laravel route gets wrong controller

Tags: laravel, vue-router

I'm building project with Laravel and Vue and i want my categories and tags urls to be like that:

`domain.com/some-tag`

`domain.com/some-category`

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index']);

Route::get('/{category}', ['as' => 'category', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index']);

Route::get('/{tag}', ['as' => 'tag', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TagController@index']);

Route::get('/{category}/{article}', ['as' => 'category.article', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index']);
```

I'm getting 404 error on my tags links and i know its because router matches "category" first and uses CategoryController.

What should I do? I don't want to make them unique by adding something like `domain.com/tags/tag-name`

I've tried to use named routes for my vue component (with Ziggy-js lib) so my link looks like

```
<a class="tags-block__link" :href="route('tag', {tag: tag.slug}).url()" v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.id">
```

But it doesn't help

Comment: `/{category}` and `/{tag}` are ambiguous; it's impossible to tell which route you want to go to like that, so the compiler defaults to the later (or earlier; I forget which) defined one. You'd need to differentiate them, like `/category/{category}` and `/tag/{tag}`, or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it should not be mixing?

You define `Route::get('/{category}'` and `Route::get('/{tag}'`. So if you open `/1` in your browser it will always run the first route it is able to find that matches the pattern. So it is always running `CategoryController@index` yes?

Your routes should be:

```
Route::get('/category/{category}', ['as' => 'category', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index']);

Route::get('/tag/{tag}', ['as' => 'tag', 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TagController@index']);
```

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing

The remaining route should do fine, cause you define it last.

Comment: I would still change the remaining route, so that it is consistent with the others and the Laravel documentation for nested resources (see controller page).

Comment: agree with you. but sometimes these are useful. But will cause problem when link will be `/category/tag`, cause it might be intended to open the last route in the list.

Comment: I thought there is a way to keep urls clean without ugly categories/tags parent. Pretty frustrating